# OpenGL Mesh Mesh splitting up in triangles When trying to apply modification by addting normal*factor

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, normals

I have a basic icosphere which i exported from blender with normals as obj.

Here is what i am doing

```
mesh->vert[i].position = mesh->vert[i].position + noise(mesh->vert[i].position) * mesh->vert[i].normal
```

for every vertex.

But the triangles are splitting up wierdly like:

[image]

The Exact Code:

```
for(int i=0;i<customModel->mesh->vertexCount;i++)
        {
            Vert tmp = customModelCopy->mesh->vert[i];
            float x = tmp.position.x;
            float y = tmp.position.y;
            float z = tmp.position.z;
            float elev = 0.0f;
            if (noiseBased)
            {
                elev = noiseGen->Evaluate(x, y, z);
                for (NoiseLayerModule* mod : moduleManager->nlModules)
                {
                    if (mod->active)
                    {
                        elev += mod->Evaluate(x, y, z);
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                float pos[3] = { x, y, z };
                float texCoord[2] = { tmp.texCoord.x, tmp.texCoord.y };
                float minPos[3] = {0, 0, 0};
                float maxPos[3] = {-1, -1, -1};
                elev =  EvaluateMeshNodeEditor(NodeInputParam(pos, texCoord, minPos, maxPos)).value;
                
            }
            tmp.position -= elev * tmp.normal;
            customModel->mesh->vert[i] = tmp;           
        }
        customModel->mesh->RecalculateNormals();
```

And For Model : https://github.com/Jaysmito101/TerraForge3D/blob/master/TerraForge3D/src/Base/Mesh.cpp
https://github.com/Jaysmito101/TerraForge3D/blob/master/TerraForge3D/src/Base/Model.cpp

Comment: Looks to me as if the model contains duplicate positions. You need to make sure to apply the same noise to all vertices with the same position, otherwise you will get cracks.

Comment: @BDL Model is from blender

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to say with this. It's allowed to have multiple vertices with the same position. You have the model, so you can check if this is the case. And if it is the case, you have to handle it in your code by making sure that you generate the same noise when the position is the same.

Comment: @BDL I will try that. But something i want to say i tried with a higher resolution mesh and the triangles were no more separstiong